# How can I accept Char input in C?

Tags: c

So  i try and compile I get a warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default] error, what am I doin wrong...?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char x;

printf("What would you like to do today?\n");
scanf("%s", &x);

if (x == "slm") {
    printf("You SLAM a Faygo!");

} else if(x == "kik") {
    printf("You KICK the Wicked Elixir!"); 
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, that's not how strings are compared in C.  `strcmp` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Three problems:

1. You need to read into a string, not a char (with due consideration of buffer overflow), e.g.:

   ```
   char x[128];

   scanf ("%128s", x);
   ```
2. You can't compare strings with ==: you need to use strcmp:

   ```
   #include <string.h>

   ...

   if (0 == strcmp (x, "slm")) { ... }
   ```
3. You should check scanf's return code for success/failure:

   ```
   if (1 != scanf (...)) {
       perror ("scanf");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```

(EXIT_FAILURE is defined in stdlib.h.)

Comment: You shouldn't be taking the address of `x` in the `scanf()` here, since `x` is already a pointer. I'd also avoid the “magic number”, 128, and use `fgets()` in preference to `scanf()`. IIRC, `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined in `stdlib.h`, which you omit to mention.

Comment: Me too, that's why I'd use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is a char. and "slm" is a string - a `char *`.

You might want to change that:

```
char *x;
```

But now you need to allocate memory. For example:

```
char *x = (char *)malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
```

Also, fvu is right - use `if(!strcmp(x,"slm"))` instead of `if(x ==slm)` (`strcmp` return 0 when the strings are the same)

Comment: I don't think this answer is appropriate to the level of knowledge the questioner seems to exhibit. Casting the return value of `malloc()` shouldn't be encouraged any more: it's not necessary and it conceals errors. Is it a good idea to demonstrate dynamic memory allocation to someone who doesn't even understand how strings are represented in *C*? Is it a good idea to show *anyone* `malloc()` without a corresponding `free()` (and an explanation of memory allocation practises, leaks, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

- You're confusing char (which is single character) and char * (which is how C deals with strings)
- You cannot meaningfully do == with char *'s the way you want to

You need to:

- Change char x to either char *x or char x[1000];
- If you use a char *, you will need to use malloc or similar to allocate space
  for it
- In either case, for production code, you will want to use
  something that limits how much data can be read in (e.g. fgets, but
  NOT gets).
- You will want to use strcmp, which returns 0 if the two
  strings are equal and non-zero if not.